# combine two csv files based on common column using awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a two CSV file which have a common column in both files along with duplicates in one file. How to merge both csv files using awk or sed?

**CSV file 1**

```
5/1/20,user,mark,Type1 445566
5/2/20,user,ally,Type1 445577
5/1/20,user,joe,Type1 445588
5/2/20,user,chris,Type1 445566
```

**CSV file 2**

```
Type1 445566,Name XYZ11
Type1 445577,Name AAA22
Type1 445588,Name BBB33
Type1 445566,Name XYZ11
```

**What I want is?**

```
5/1/20,user,mark,Type1 445566,Name XYZ11
5/2/20,user,ally,Type1 445577,Name AAA22
5/1/20,user,joe,Type1 445588,Name BBB33
5/2/20,user,chris,Type1 445566,Name XYZ11
```

So is there a bash command in Linux/Unix to achieve this? Can we do this using awk or sed?

Basically, I need to match column 4 of CSV file 1 with column 1 of CSV file 2 and merge both csv's.

**Tried following command:**

**Command:**

paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 1-2 ./test1.csv | sed 's/$/,Type1/') test2.csv

**Got Result:**

5/1/20,user,Type1,Type1 445566,Name XYZ11

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to install the `join` utility, this command works:

```
join -t, -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 -1 4 -2 1 file1.csv file2.csv
```

**Explanation:**

`-t,` identify the field separator as comma (',')

`-o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2` format the output to be "file1col1, file1col2, file1col3, file2col1, file2col2`

`-1 4` join by column 4 in file1

`-2 1` join by column 1 in file2

For additional usage information for `join`, reference [the join manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join).

**Edit:** You specifically asked for the solution using `awk` or `sed` so here is the `awk` implementation:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} {print $1","$2","$3","$4"," a[$4]}' \
    file2.csv \
    file1.csv
```

**Explanation**:

`-F","` Delimit by the comma character

`NR==FNR` Read the first file argument (notice in the above solution that we're passing file2 first)

`{a[$1] = $2; next}` In the current file, save the contents of Column2 in an array that uses Column1 as the key

`{print $1","$2","$3","$4"," a[$4]}` Read file1 and using Column4, match the value to the key's value from the array. Print Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, and the key's value.

Comment: I did not know of `join`'s `-o` option! Thank you very much :D.

Comment: Had to change it a bit to work: `join -t, -o'1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2' -j1 file1.csv file2.csv`

Answer (score 0):

The two example input files seem to be already appropriately sorted, so you just have to put them side by side, and `paste` is good for this; however you want to remove some `,`-separated columns from `file1`, and you can use `cut` for that; but you also want to insert another (constant) column, and `sed` can do it. A possible command is this:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 1-2 file1 | sed 's/$/,abcd/') file2
```

Actually `sed` can do the whole processing of `file1`, and the output can be pided into `paste`, which uses `-` to capture it from the standard input:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^,]+,){2}).*/\1abcd/' file1 | paste -d, - file2
```

Comment: Thank you @Enrico Maria De Angelis for a prompt response. By just pasting the file 2 columns won't work I tried this earlier. What I was trying is, extracting the column 2 of file 2 by matching it with column 4 of file 1 and colum 1 of file 2

Comment: @Srujanreddy have you tried my command on the two file you have provided here?

Comment: I have tried your command with a slight change and it gave me result like this Command used: paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 1-2 ./test1.csv | sed 's/$/,Type1/') test2.csv Result: 5/1/20,user,Type1,Type1 445566,Name XYZ11

Comment: @Srujanreddy avoid putting code in the comments. Update the question instead, especially if you have to provide a more relevant input and output.